# Shell scripting GUI

Tags: linux, user-interface, shell

I want to write a shell script which has a simple GUI interface to show some messages.Is there any GUI library available which can run on any Linux OS?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvYrhodJs0g

Comment: notify-send has to be downloaded first using libnotify

Answer (score 1):

Gnome has the **zenity** command, which you use like this:

```
zenity --info --text "message here"
```

Note that the command waits until the user acknowledges the message. Also, make sure your $DISPLAY environment variable is set in the shell's environment, or you will get an error like this: *(zenity:14693): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:*

Comment: Solved that error.It happens when you login as root in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

"On any linux OS"? No chance... :) But "dialog" is very common stuff. Here is a good example about it:

http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html